# Can I iterate a datasource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a control, and I want to interate through its datasource, is that possible?

The control is bound to a repeater, but I also want to loop through the items using inline code on the top of the .ascx control page.

Is this possible?

**Update**

I am binding to a repeater, and the thing bound to the repeater is a List collection.

I tried:

```
myRepeater.DataSource
```

And I don't get anything via intellisense, casting to `List<UserPRofile>` doesn't work either.

Comment: "bound to repeater" meaning what? Is the control contained inside the repeater or is the repeater part of the control?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just refer to the control's DataSource property and it will return whatever you originally bound to the control. You'll want to cast the return value to the appropriate type.

```
var dataSource = (List<MyClass>)myRepeater.DataSource; // your control
```

Bear in mind that if you plan to make changes to it and want it to be reflected in the control then you should use an appropriate datasource that supports 2-way binding, such as a [BindList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx).

Comment: Can you update your question with some more code? Show us the Repeater markup and the databinding. It also sounds like you're using a user control. Are you binding the list to the user controls and attempting to access their datasources? That would be separate from the repeater's datasource.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to access a repeater's datasource that located inside an user control. I recommend you to expose the datasource as a property and use it to loop outside the user control as well as to bind your repeater.

Also you can use Repeater.Items collection and get each binded row as [RepeaterItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.aspx) instance.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem repeaterItem in myRepeater.Items)
{
    lblResult.Text += " " + repeaterItem.Text;
}
```